# Vulkan: How to download image from GPU to RAM

Tags: vulkan

Once an image has been rendered onto the GPU, what are the steps of getting that image from GPU memory onto CPU RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[vkCmdCopyImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdCopyImage.html) or [vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer.html). Record it into command buffer and submit it to queue.